# Phase Space Contributions to Decays with Fixed Momentum

Tags: particle-physics, density-of-states, pions

Neglecting helicity, consider the decays
$π^-\rightarrow e^-\bar{ν_e}$ and$π^-\rightarrow μ^-\bar{ν}_μ$. I understand that from Fermi's golden rule, the decay probability should be proportional to the density of states $ρ(E)$. This is calculated typically from
$$ρ(E) = \frac{dN}{dE} = \frac{dN}{dp}\frac{dp}{dE} = \frac{V4πp^2}{(2π\hbar)^3}\frac{dp}{dE} $$
With V some normalising volume which cancels later.
The crux of my question is how we tackle $\frac{dp}{dE} $. I have seen the following approach used:
$$E = m_πc^2 = pc+\sqrt{p^2c^2+m_l^2c^4}$$
where $m_l$ is the mass of either the electron or the muon, $E_ν \approx p_νc$ and $p_ν = p_e$ by conservation of momentum. Taking the derivative with respect to $p$ then,
$$dE/dp = c+\frac{pc^2}{ \sqrt{p^2c^2+m_l^2c^4}} = \frac{m_π}{m_π-p/c}$$
We can then work out from 4-momenta (or otherwise) an expression for $p$, which is the following constant:
$$p=\frac{m_π^2-m_l^2}{2m_π}c$$ and substitude everything in to get our density of states for both the electron and muon decay modes, the ratio of which gives the ratio of decay probabilities. This method is of course not specific to only pion decays.

But, what sense does it even make to take a derivative of our centre of mass energy $E$, a **constant** $m_πc^2$, with respect to our momentum of the final state $p$, also a constant given above. From basic calculus I'd expect derivatives of $0$! Do we need to treat $m_π$ as a varying parameter to have this method make any sense - and if so, how can we justify doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basic calculus.  Of course the function/line $E'(p)$ evaluated at a point is a point. You've faked yourself out by the way you miswrote your basic functional dependence,
$$E(p) =   pc+\sqrt{p^2c^2+m_l^2c^4},\leadsto \\
E'(p)=c+\frac{pc^2}{ \sqrt{p^2c^2+m_l^2c^4}} ~~. $$

You then invert the first function to $p(E)$, and evaluate at the ***point*** $E=m_\pi c^2$,
$$
E'(p(m_\pi c^2))= c+ \frac{p(m_\pi c^2)~~c^2}{ \sqrt{(p(m_\pi c^2))^2c^2+m_l^2c^4}} 
$$
to get your correct implicit answer.